# react-native Error : NSInternalInconsistencyException - UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() failed to allocate CGBitampContext:

Tags: react-native, ios17

We are getting follwong error suddenly on our ios app from ios 17+ version.

We dont know which library needs to be updated. we have used multiple libraries

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() failed to allocate CGBitampContext: size={0, 0}, scale=3.000000, bitmapInfo=0x2002. Use UIGraphicsImageRenderer to avoid this assert.

Answer (score 0):

Run the search "UIGraphicsBeginImageContext" in the project (do not forget to include `node_modules` path because this folder hidden for search by default). After that do find GitHub issues for these libraries.